# Using a vncviewer with ssh tunneling - won't connect

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vnc, tunnel

I'm having a problem trying to get a vnc connection (vinagre, I'm using Ubuntu) to a computer at my work. It says on their website that you need to tunnel via ssh first, so I've typed in:

```
ssh -l hjohnson -L 5904:barcelona.aip.de:5902 login.aip.de
```

Confirmed it with my password and it works. I have a connection to login.aip.de now, and I can access my files by doing ssh again to just barcelona.aip.de. However it then tells me to access with a vncviewer I need to write:

```
vncviewer localhost:5904
```

But this doesn't work!? I'm writing vinagre instead of vncviewer, and I've tried writing barcelona.aip.de instead of localhost, but I just says that the connection has been refused by the host.
Any ideas please?! It's a public holiday here in Germany and I really need to access some things.

Comment: Don't negative rep me without explaining why?! It's a genuine problem/question.

Comment: Are you sure that your computer over there is powered-on ? Is it (networkly) accessible from the computer `login.aip.de` ? Once you're SSHed, can you ping your computer ? Can you `nmap`it to see if 5902 is open and respond ?

Comment: Yup it's definitely switched on, I'm logged on to that computer and it's locked, but definitely on. :)
How do I ping it or nmap it, please? Really sorry, I have no idea with these kinds of things. I haven't had a lot of experience.

Comment: Try asking on SuperUser.com if you don't get a good answer here. (I would vote to migrate but 3 people have already voted to close.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged on your computer, we'll not really have to ping it : we assume that it's well connected to the network, and thus, powered ;).

First, on your remote machine (`barcelona.aip.de`), try the command `ps aux` and look for "vnc" : if VNC is launched on your machine, you should see it in the list of active processes.

From the computer `login.aip.de`, install nmap 
 - maybe with `apt-get install nmap`, if it is a Debian or Ubuntu machine
 - then make a `nmap -p 5900-6000 barcelona.aip.de` to see what ports are open on your desktop machine.

Maybe VNC is not running on port 5902 but on 5901, or 5903.

Cheers,

K.

Comment: Thanks :) VNC doesn't seem to be in the list of active processes, and nmap isn't installed on that login.aip.de place.. hmmm. In fact it seems like a bit of a ghost computer. I'm pretty sure it's a linux computer - is there a command I could use to remotely install nmap?

Comment: Let NMAP go for the moment : if your desktop is not running VNC, it's not a deal to prove that you can't access to it. You have to find a way to launch VNCServer on `barcelona`. Do you need graphical access or just accessing the datas ?

Comment: Graphical access preferably :) I just typed vncserver on barcelona and it says
New 'X' desktop is barcelona:2

Starting applications specified in /home/hjohnson/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/hjohnson/.vnc/barcelona:2.log

Comment: Type `netstat -taupn` on Barcelona and look for which port is opened by VNCserver (probably 5902, or something like this). And from your remote computer, relaunch the tunnel as you made it, and try your VNC connexion. And hope :)

Comment: Haha oh I'm so useless. There seems to be several different things with something /Xvnc next to them? Like 6001/2/3, 5901/2/3, 5801/2/3.. Should those all be open?!
Then do I exit that ssh connection and type 
ssh -l hjohnson -L 5904:barcelona.aip.de:5902 login.aip.de or so again?

Comment: VNCServer listen on port 5901 by default, so you should try `ssh -l hjohnson -L 5904:barcelona.aip.de:5901 login.aip.de` then launch your VNC client and connect to localhost:5904

Comment: Ooh.. I have something! Although it's really basic and looks nothing like my desktop on that computer

Comment: Not a problem. Nice to have helped you. Nice day.